Ros2-foxy, Gazebo starts working after three times starts
I take a problem with Gazebo, when I started simulation for my ros2 project. It is necessary to restart Пazebo several times for correct operation. And I have an error:
[robot_state_publisher-1] 1720762450.823432 [0] robot_stat: using network interface eth0 (udp/172.20.76.38) selected arbitrarily from: eth0, docker0, wlan0
My yaml, xacro and launch.py files:
my_controllers.yaml
controller_manager:
ros__parameters:
update_rate: 30
use_sim_time: true
diff_cont:
  type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

joint_broad:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_cont:
ros__parameters:
publish_rate: 50.0

base_frame_id: base_link

left_wheel_names: ['left_wheel_joint']
right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
wheel_separation: 0.55
wheel_radius: 0.125

use_stamped_vel: false

ros2_control.xacro
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
        <command_interface name="velocity">
            <param name="min">-1</param>
            <param name="max">1</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position" />
        <state_interface name="velocity" />
    </joint>
    <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
        <command_interface name="velocity">
            <param name="min">-1</param>
            <param name="max">1</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity" />
        <state_interface name="position" />
    </joint>
</ros2_control>

<gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
        <parameters>$(find articubot_one)/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

launch_sim.launch.py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.actions import Node
def generate_launch_description():
# Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
# !!! MAKE SURE YOU SET THE PACKAGE NAME CORRECTLY !!!

package_name='articubot_one' #<--- CHANGE ME

rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
            )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
)

# Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
gazebo_params_path = os.path.join(
              get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','gazebo_params.yaml')

gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
            launch_arguments={'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file ' + gazebo_params_path }.items()
     )

# Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                               '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                    output='screen')


diff_drive_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner.py",
    arguments=["diff_cont"],
)

joint_broad_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner.py",
    arguments=["joint_broad"],
)

twist_mux_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','twist_mux.yaml')
twist_mux = Node(
        package="twist_mux",
        executable="twist_mux",
        parameters=[twist_mux_params, {'use_sim_time': True}],
        remappings=[('/cmd_vel_out','/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped')]
    )



# Launch them all!
return LaunchDescription([
    rsp,
    gazebo,
    spawn_entity,
    diff_drive_spawner,
    joint_broad_spawner
])

Any hints and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I tried to turn off all network interfaces without eth0. Tried to explicitly specify which network interface to use for ros2. But it didn't work.
